# Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#

Here is my c# code

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\MYREMOTESERVER123\\PATH1\\PATH2\\PATH3_20130315.4\\PATH4\\PATH5", "*.*");
```

I can **successfully** run unit test against ABOVE path in my local dev machine

```
\\MYREMOTESERVER123\PATH1\PATH2\PATH3_20130315.4\PATH4\PATH5
```

But when this code runs on remote machine.. I get the following error..

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '\\MYREMOTESERVER123\PATH1\PATH2\PATH3_20130315.4\PATH4\PATH5\'
```

I don't know what is going on .. Please help.. Thanks..

Comment: The first thing I would check is permissions. Can you access the share with the same credentials that is running the application on the server? Do you run the code on the server in a windows service?

Comment: On what account does your program currently running into? Please try to run Visual Studio on Administrator mode and see if that will work. Can you also try to check the event viewer and see what's beeing logged in there?

Comment: don't you need the last back slashes at the end of the FilePath 
`string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\MYREMOTESERVER123\PATH1\PATH2\PATH3_20130315.4\PATH4\PATH5\", "*.*");` also with the `@` you don't have to use the `"\\"` double backslashes it becomes a `literal` now